# Flag controlled while loop to search txt file

Tags: c++, if-statement, while-loop, flags

Given a .txt file containing this data (it can contain any number of similar lines):

```
hammer#9.95
shovel#12.35
```

Using a flag controlled while loop in C++, when an item name is searched for in the imported .txt file, the price of the item (separated by the hash) should be returned.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<fstream>
#include<string>

using namespace std;

int main()
{


inFile.open(invoice1.txt);

char name;
char search;
int price;


ifstream inFile;
ofstream outFile;
bool found = false;

    if (!inFile)
        {
        cout<<"File not found"<<endl;
        }


outFile.open(invoice1.txt)

inFile>>name;
inFile>>price;

cout<<"Enter the name of an item to find its price: "<<endl;
cin>>search;

    while (!found)
    {


        if (found)
            found = true;

    }

cout<<"The item "<<search<<" costs "<<price<<"."<<endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You might want to start by posting your code so that we have a frame of reference in describing a solution to you.

Comment: The description is pretty straightforward, so if there is some specific thing you are struggling with, please ask about that.  In a loop, read each line, if the line starts with the thing you are searching for, output everything after the # on the line.

Comment: Thank you for posting a copy of your homework assignment, followed by your answer. Unfortunately, it seems that you have submitted your answer to stackoverflow.com instead of your instructor. stackoverflow.com is not a website that grades your instructor's class, but for asking questions and obtaining answers. If you have a question that relates to your homework assignment, you should explicitly write what it is, instead of just posting your code, and make everyone guess what your question is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following variables can only hold a single character.

```
char name;
char search;
```

A fix would be to replace them with for example`char name[30];` this variable can hold 30 characters.

But it's best to use `std::string` as it can grow dynamically to any size.

```
std::string name;
std::string search;
```

You also open the same file twice, once with read permissions, and once with write permissions. In your case, you only need to read it. If you needed write/read access, you can do that using the stream flags `std::fstream s("filename.txt",std::ios::in | std::ios::out);`

Here's a full example of what you are trying to accomplish:

```
std::cout << "Enter the name of an item to find its price: " << std::endl;
std::string search;
std::cin >> search;

std::ifstream inFile("invoice1.txt");

if (inFile) // Make sure no error ocurred
{
    std::string line;
    std::string price;

    while (getline(inFile, line)) // Loop trought all lines in the file
    {
        std::size_t f = line.find('#');

        if (f == std::string::npos)  // If we can't find a '#', ignore line.
            continue;

        std::string item_name = line.substr(0, f);

        if (item_name == search) //note: == is a case sensitive comparison.
        {
            price = line.substr(f + 1); // + 1 to dodge '#' character
            break; // Break loop, since we found the item. No need to process more lines.
        }
    }

    if (price.empty())
        std::cout << "Item: " << search << " does not exist." << std::endl;
    else
    {
        std::cout << "Item: " << search << " found." << std::endl;
        std::cout << "Price: " << price << std::endl;

    }

    inFile.close(); // close file
}
```

Comment: Why did you choose to use the format 'std::' rather than 'using namespace std;'?

Comment: I usually work with multiple namespaces, and I like to know which function I'm using exactly from which library, and also the obvious one: to avoid name collisions.